# How should I set up live reloading for a full stack app?

Tags: node.js, angular, nodemon

I am working on a simple full stack app consisting of an Express server which provides an API for interacting with a database, and an Angular frontend that interfaces with the API to display data from the database. This works fine when deployed in production, and on my development machine, I can also use `nodemon` and `ng serve` to automatically reload my backend and my frontend respectively when I make changes to their files.

The problem arises when trying to combine the two. `nodemon` does not reload when I make changes to my Angular app, unless I `ng build` it first. The frontend needs some data to display, so `ng serve` by itself is not enough, since there is no connection to the Express server + database. If I use `ng serve` and `nodemon` to run both frontend and backend at the same time I run into cross site request forgery errors, since they are running on different ports. Currently I'm trying to hack something together that will automatically enable cross site requests only when running in development, but it's kind of a headache and feels ugly, surely there must be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

did u try option ng serve **--disable-host-check** for dev?
also for display on production what new version come - u can use gulp (or webpack/babel) and place version into angular environment.ts file and version.json file (placed into assets). In guard each some time you check version from version.json and if versions is different - show modal to for reload or do it by yourself.

Comment: --disable-host-check doesn't seem to change anything. maybe I'm using it wrong, is there anything else I have to do except enable the flag? After that I don't really understand what you mean, sorry.